# How to invoke async/await spread across multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I was following along the MDN article on async/await and understanding it fairly well and then
I had a brain fart, and I'm not sure what's going on now. This example is an MDN example from the article on async/await.

```js
async function makeResult(items) {
  let newArr;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    newArr[i].push('word_' + i);
  }
  return newArr;
}

async function getResult() {
  let result = await makeResult(["1", "2"]);
  console.log(result);
}
```

How do I get this code to log the result to the console? I get errors when trying to call these functions from the main flow of the program. What am I supposed to do? I'm familiar with Promises, .then() chaining, and how to use async await in one basic async function, but not sure what to do here.

Edit: The problem was that newArr wasn't initialized as an empty array, and that I was pushing to newArr[i] instead of newArr. This is all very strange since the code snippet on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await was written incorrectly.

Comment: May you share how you are calling the functions and how you are logging the result?

Comment: Welll, all these functions do is synchronous, not sure how that is supposed to demonstrate async/await? Can you link this example?

Comment: As @connexo said, there's no async code here... async/await relates to promises.

Comment: @connexo aren’t they’re still async? just that they’re fulfilled immediately?

Comment: @evolutionxbox True. The problem was syntactical in nature.

Comment: @embracethefuture There is seemingly no purpose to `await` here... what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Brad Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_downsides_of_asyncawait The example is from that page.

Comment: Why did you not pick the answer that has explanations as of what exactly was wrong with the code?

Comment: Glad you found the error on MDN. The error message "newArr is undefined" is a bit unusual in that it literally means the _value_ of `newArr` is `undefined` and not that the variable was not declared. I've voted to close the question as a typo because that is what it is.

Comment: *I get errors when trying to call these functions from the main flow of the program* That is not a helpful statement. What are the error messages? Why didn't you add them to your question?

Comment: @embracethefuture Honestly, this tutorial isn't the best.  I think it would be better if you found a different tutorial, or post a specific question with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just do it like below, because you did wrong in makeResult(items) function array declaration/use block:

```
  function makeResult(items) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      newArr.push('word_' + i);
    }
    return newArr;
  }

  async function getResult() {
    let result = await makeResult(["1", "2"]);
    console.log(result);
  }
```

//testing

> getResult()

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. I get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error

Comment: look i added the result screen shot, may be you did some mistake please check again

Comment: yeah you were right, the code snippet on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await was wrong. newArr has to be initialized to [] and newArr[i].push is wrong (it should be newArr.push. I'm not sure why MDN's code snippet was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is asynchronous but doesn't do any async work, is it really asynchronous?  If a tree falls in the woods...

The first function would return a`Promise<Array<string>>` if the code in it worked, the second function would return a `Promise<undefined>` because there's no `return`. You can see this by commenting out the first line in the second function body, then `console.log(getResult())`. The first function has logic problems (newArr is undefined, but it looks like the loop wants it to be a 2d array).

To log the result of an async function to the console, you can do what you already know (using `.then`), or `await` it in another `async` function:

```
const foo = async () => true

// this works
foo().then(console.log)

// this also works
;(async () => {
  const bool = await foo()
  console.log(bool)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you've shown is that you're wrongfully using the array.

You need to initialize with an empty array:

```
let newArr = [];
```

In your loop, you're trying to use `push` on non-existent array-elements. Instead you want to use it on the array itself:

```
newArr[i].push('word_' + i);
```

```js
async function makeResult(items) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    newArr.push('word_' + i);
  }
  return newArr;
}

async function getResult() {
  let result = await makeResult(["1", "2"]);
  console.log(result);
}

getResult();
```

As it turns out, [MDN has this exact faulty code example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_downsides_of_asyncawait). I've submitted an issue for it: https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/1202

Comment: async keyword no more require for makeResult(items) @connexo

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code.

1 - Your `newArr` is undefined since you haven't initialized it.

2 - You are trying to push into an `array` that is in `newArr[i]` instead of pushing into `newArr`. Since there is nothing in `newArr`, the push returns undefined.

Async works just the way you have written here. You can combine the promises to wait for each other. And, the return statement will convert into a promise.

For example, the following:

```
async function foo() {
   return 1
}
```

...is equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
   return Promise.resolve(1)
}
```

Looking at your code,

```
async function makeResult(items) {
  let newArr= [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    newArr.push('word_' + i);
  }
  return newArr;
}

async function getResult() {
  let result = await makeResult(["1", "2"]);
  console.log(result);
}

getResult();
```